# clojure.spec/unform returning non-conforming values

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I've been getting on quite well with clojure.spec for the most part. However, I came to a problem that I couldn't figure out when dealing with `unform`. Here's a loose spec for Hiccup to get us moving:

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as s])

(s/def ::hiccup
  (s/and
      vector?
      (s/cat
        :name       keyword?
        :attributes (s/? map?)
        :contents   (s/* ::contents))))

(s/def ::contents
  (s/or
    :element-seq (s/* ::hiccup)
    :element     ::hiccup
    :text        string?))
```

Now before we get carried away, let's see if it works with a small passing case.

```
(def example [:div])

(->> example
     (s/conform ::hiccup))

;;=> {:name :h1}
```

Works like a charm. But can we then undo our conformance?

```
(->> example
     (s/conform ::hiccup)
     (s/unform ::hiccup))

;;=> (:div)
```

Hmm, that should be a vector. Am I missing something? Let's see what spec has to say about this.

```
(->> example
     (s/conform ::hiccup)
     (s/unform ::hiccup)
     (s/explain ::hiccup))

;; val: (:div) fails spec: :user/hiccup predicate: vector?
;;=> nil
```

Indeed, it fails. So the question: How do I get this to work correctly?

Comment: I don't think it is possible.
Unform can restore the shape of the data, but not the type... because the type is not specified, just a predicate.

Comment: @Hoagy Did you already try s/merge instead of s/and ?(https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/merge)

Comment: @TimothyPratley But is that the correct behavior? I think not. It's not a direct analog, but I think the current behavior is like `unform`ing a `conform`ed value on `(s/and int? pos?)` and getting a float. Doesn't that seem wrong?

Comment: @JeroenvanDijk I didn't, but that's because `s/merge` is for map-validating specs, which this is not.

Comment: I agree that it would be much nicer if unforming was symmetric. Having thought about it some more it seems like it could be implemented (at least for Clojure collections) by just keeping track of `vector?` and `set?` as a special case.

Comment: @HoagyCarmichael You are right it is not possible right now. It is the same as this issue: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2021?focusedCommentId=43842#comment-43842. Maybe you can upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

Late response here. I had not realised how old this question was but since I had already written a reply I might as well submit it.

Taking the spec that you provide for `::hiccup`:

```clj
(s/def ::hiccup
  (s/and
      vector?
      (s/cat
        :name       keyword?
        :attributes (s/? map?)
        :contents   (s/* ::contents))))
```

The `vector?` spec within `and` will test the input data against that predicate. Unluckily as you have experienced, it doesn't unform to a vector.

Something that you can do to remedy this is to add an intermediate spec that will act as the identity when conforming and will act as desired when unforming. E.g.

```clj
(s/def ::hiccup                                                                                                                                                                                           
  (s/and vector?                                                                                                                                                                                          
         (s/conformer vec vec)                                                                                                                                                                            
         (s/cat                                                                                                                                                                                           
          :name       keyword?                                                                                                                                                                            
          :attributes (s/? map?)                                                                                                                                                                          
          :contents   (s/* ::contents)))) 

(s/unform ::hiccup (s/conform ::hiccup [:div]))

;;=> [:div]
```

`(s/conformer vec vec)` Will be a no-op for everything that satisfies `vector?` and using `vec` as the unforming function in the conformer will make sure that the result to unforming the whole `and` spec stays a vector.

I am new to spec myself and this was how I got it working as you intend. Bear in mind it might not be the way in which it was intended to be used by spec's designers.

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, I made a spec that checks for a vector and unforms to a vector:

```
(defn vector-spec
  "Create a spec that it is a vector and other conditions and unforms to a vector.

  Ex (vector-spec (s/spec ::binding-form))
     (vector-spec (s/* integer?))"
  [form]
  (let [s (s/spec (s/and vector? form))]
    (reify
      s/Specize
      (specize* [_] s)
      (specize* [_ _] s)

      s/Spec
      (conform* [_ x] (s/conform* s x))
      (unform* [_ x] (vec (s/unform* s x))) ;; <-- important
      (explain* [_ path via in x] (s/explain s path via in x))
      (gen*  [_ overrides path rmap] (s/gen* s overrides path rmap))
      (with-gen* [_ gfn] (s/with-gen s gfn))
      (describe* [_] (s/describe* s)))))
```

In your example, you would use it like this:

```
(s/def ::hiccup
  (vector-spec
    (s/cat
      :name       keyword?
      :attributes (s/? map?)
      :contents   (s/* ::contents))))
```